# Converting Text Field to Numerical Value (Getting NaN)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have this bit of code, it's supposed to take the value from one field, and calculate the value from it based on a certain percentage (in this case 60%).

I created a hidden field to store the value in the html, but when I run the calculation and check it in Firebug it gets a NaN value. Can anyone tell me what I can do to produce the number I need?

```
 (Apply_RequestedAmtX_r != 0 & Apply_RequestedAdvanceAmtY_r !=0){
    var AmtX= ($('#Apply_RequestedAdvanceAmtX_r').val());
    var AmtY= ($("#Apply_AmtYAfterSplit_r").val());
    var MaxAMT = parseInt((AmtY*60)/100);
        $('#mna').val(MaxAMT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`val` returns a string. Now, the way you're using those variables, they'll get automagically converted to numbers (although it's best practice to parse them yourself).

One or the other of your values has a character in it that prevents the value from being automatically converted to a number; and then since that's `NaN`, any math involving it will be `NaN`. If you examine `AmtX` and `AmyY` in Firebug before using them, you should see whatever that character is.

Again, parsing isn't the actual problem here, but you're using `parseInt` in exactly the wrong place (unless you were trying to use it to truncate the fractional portion of the number, in which case there are better choices). Here are the right places:

```
var AmtX= parseInt($('#Apply_RequestedAdvanceAmtX_r').val(), 10);
var AmtY= parseInt($("#Apply_AmtYAfterSplit_r").val(), 10);
var MaxAMT = (AmtY*60)/100;
```

`MaxAMT` will likely have a fractional portion. If you want `MaxAMT` to be an integer, then:

```
var MaxAMT = Math.round((AmtY*60)/100);
// or
var MaxAMT = Math.floor(AmtY*60)/100);
// or
var MaxAMT = Math.ceil(AmtY*60)/100);
```

...depending on your needs.

Comment: The problem I'm having now is, when I tab out of the Amount Y field the calculation is made. Which is awesome, but the next part of the code is a stipulation that if Amount X is greater than Amount Y than Max Amt will replace the Amount Y value. It triggers the alert I have setup, but deletes the amount in the field leaving it blank.